# Why does running my files through `tar cf` before `gzip` change their content?

Tags: linux, unix, compression, gzip, tar

Let's first create two files with identical content:

```
echo "content" > file1
echo "content" > file2
```

Now, if we use `gzip` to compress each one, the files are identical, unsurprisingly:

```
gzip --no-name file1
gzip --no-name file2
diff -u file1.gz file2.gz
```

(Unsurprisingly, the `diff` command returns no output.)

However, let's say we do this with the files:

```
tar cf - file1 | gzip --no-name > file1.tar.gz
tar cf - file2 | gzip --no-name > file2.tar.gz
```

What happens when we run `diff`?

```
% diff -u file1.tar.gz file2.tar.gz
Binary files file1.tar.gz and file2.tar.gz differ
```

This is surprising to me. What options do I need to pass in to `tar` so that the output of the two `tar ... | gzip ...` commands are identical?

For reference, when I run

```
tar cf - file | gzip --no-name > file1.tar.gz
tar cf - file | gzip --no-name > file2.tar.gz
```

the outputs are identical. So it's *not* that the output of `tar` is changing based on when I run it, so it must be the case that `tar` is incorporating the last modified time of its input into the tarred output. This isn't the behavior that I want.

Answer (score 3):

The [TAR file format](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html) contains the file name and other directory information so the files will differ unless they contain the same files with the same names, sizes, etc.

Comment: @ElizabethLin ... and different names.  A TAR archive contains a directory of the files that are bundled in the archive.  That directory contains the file name, size, owner, perms, and other file system details.  Please read the linked document before down voting me.

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems to answer the question. Tar two files of different names, receive different tar bundle...

Answer (score 0):

To see what's going on have a look at this

```
echo "tea" > file1
echo "tea" > file2
```

Now run the following two commands.

```
tar cf - file1
tar cf - file1 | gzip -c --no-name | gunzip -c
```

You'll noticed that in both cases the output is identical ie the option `--no-name` to gzip has had no effect whatsoever (It did remove it's own timestamp but it didn't remove the filename from the tar output). This is because the file name is part of the tar format and gzip does not parse what it gets from tar. This is why when you have the same filename you get the same identical output.